# Write SQL query that returns results for each sorted value in main column

Tags: sql

I'm working on a project related with my college and I have the following tables:

- **user - table with information about registered students**

[image]

- **payment - table with information about payments**

[image]

- **lesson - table with list of lessons.**

Possible statuses of lessons:

- CONFIRMED - lesson happened successfully
- SCHEDULED - for future
  lessons
- CANCELED - for lessons that were canceled

Each lesson appears in table only one time. Lesson status is being updated.

[image]

I need to write a SQL query that returns for each country:

- number of registered users
- % of users, who made their first payment in 3 days after registration
- % of users, who made their first payment in 3 days after registration and had 2 confirmed
  lessons in 7 days after registration

But aside from using `DISTINCT` to sort the table with non repeated elements, I'm stuck with the subqueries required to filter the information using each country as reference.

Comment: Can you show the query you've gotten written so far?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to adapt this to your SQL dialect (mainly adding intervals on timestamps). I guess the rest should work (not tested anyways).

```sql
WITH pay3day AS (
    SELECT u.id
    FROM user u
    INNER JOIN payment p ON p.user_id = u.id
    WHERE p.datetime <= u.date_joined + INTERVAL '3 days'
    GROUP BY u.id
), less2in7 AS (
    SELECT u.id
    FROM user u
    INNER JOIN lesson l ON l.user_id = u.id
    WHERE l.status = 'CONFIRMED'
        AND l.datetime <= u.date_joined + INTERVAL '7 days'
    GROUP BY u.id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
)
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS a,
    (COUNT(p.id) * 100.0) / COUNT(*) AS b,
    (COUNT(p.id + l.id) * 100.0) / COUNT(*) AS c
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN pay3day p ON p.id = u.id
LEFT JOIN less2in7 l ON l.id = u.id
GROUP BY u.country_code
```